# BazaarVoice BV Pixel trackTransaction event from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, cron

I am working on a vueJS project where BV Pixel trackTransaction event is already implemented on the frontend but my client wants me to put it into the CRON's specific function and the cron is written in PHP and this code of BV Pixel is in Javascript so there's no way i can run this script into the server from CRON file so how can i achieve this can i run this script from PHP or do i need to do something else here.

https://knowledge.bazaarvoice.com/wp-content/conversations/en_US/Collect/bvpixel.html

```
 <script async type="text/javascript" src="https://apps.bazaarvoice.com/deployments/<client_name>/<site_ID>/<environment>/<locale>/bv.js"></script>

 <!--load transaction event and parameters-->
 <script type="text/javascript">
 window.bvCallback = function (BV) {
 BV.pixel.trackTransaction({
   "currency" : "value",
   "orderId" : "value",
   "total" : "value",
   "items" : [
     {
       "name" : "value",
       "price" : "value",
       "quantity" : "value",
       "productId" : "value",
       "imageURL" :  "value", 
     },
   ],
   "email" : "value",
   "locale" : "value",
   "nickname" : "value"
 });
 };
 </script>
```

Comment: You need to go and check with that provider, whether they offer some API to push data from the server side.

Comment: (I don't see what sense a cron is supposed to make here though. Even if you did the tracking from the server side, it would still need to happen when the specific "events" you want to track, actually occur. Or you would need to _record_ those occurrences in some sort of queue, so that the cron script can then get them from there and send the data.)